# Ofbiz call service executeFind (get data from the database)

Tags: java, web-services, ofbiz

Im trying to get all Leads / Contact / Accounts from the database.
So i try to use executeFind but this is not working. Im always getting 0 rows with the run service (also in java).

As entityName i set as example : PartyContactInfo

what am i doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, XmlRpcException {

XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL("http://10.0.2.19:8080/webtools/control/xmlrpc"));
config.setEnabledForExceptions(true);
config.setEnabledForExtensions(true);

XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
client.setConfig(config);

Map paramMap = new HashMap();

//Required Fields
paramMap.put("login.username", "admin");
paramMap.put("login.password", "opentaps");
paramMap.put("entityName", "Party");

Object[] params = new Object[]{paramMap};

Map result = (Map) client.execute("executeFind", params);

System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: Some snippets from your code might be helpful

Comment: The service is always returnning listIt=null. Normaly the service should return all the information in the party table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spitting out the server log filles it looks like an internal error from the ofbiz server. reported it to Ofbiz if they can patch it! And hopefully will those services be back on track very soon.

Answer (score 1):

Never touched ofbiz before, but my guess is that the parameters which are sent in are wrong.

The methods which you are trying to call are documented here (I think): 
http://www.opentaps.org/javadocs/version-1.0/framework/api/org/ofbiz/common/FindServices.html
in particular:

```
public static Map executeFind(DispatchContext dctx, Map context)
```

So unless the URL you're calling somehow internally defines the first argument, you need to give it that as well. Something tells me that the "context" should be sorted out on the server side though. Next what I suspect might be wrong, is what looks like authentication information. Are you sure you're supposed to give the login-info in the same "bag" of arguments as the name of table you're trying to view?

I know this answer is incomplete, but to get a serious answer you'll have to let the audience know exactly which rpc-server you are working with (so that they may check the docs). Because otherwise your only hope is that someone who knows ofbiz inside-out (or at least relatively well) will stumble on this question. Good luck!